# facebook api date format

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've been working on facebook application. But I've faced with strange bug(?).

It I'm trying to get detailed info about any event using graph api start_date differs from the one if I'm trying to get it using fql. for example:

1. https://graph.facebook.com/209798352393506/ - start date is 2011-05-26T19:00:00
2. https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20eid%2C%20name%2C%20tagline%2C%20pic%2C%20host%20%2C%20start_time%20from%20event%20where%20eid%20%3D209798352393506 - start time is 1306461600. Which in human readable format equals to Fri, 27 May 2011 02:00:00 GMT.

As you can see difference between got dates is 5 hours. Somtimes I'm getting dates which differ for 8 hours, sometimes - 6.

Correct date is the first one:
http://www.facebook.com/events/209798352393506/

I can't figure out what happens. All events I'm trying to view are from Denmark. My timezone is Europe/Kiev. Difference is 1 hour.

Is this a facebook's bug? Or documented feature? Or am I doing something wrong?

Link to the documentation or another answer in stackoverflow would be enough.

Here is two events

http://www.facebook.com/events/290600150977115/ - starts on 2012-03-22 at 20:00

http://www.facebook.com/events/289501924395338/ - starts on 2012-03-03 at 21:00

But. Using FQL I'm getting that first event starts on 2012-03-23 at 04:00. Difference is 8 hours. And the second one starts on 2012-03-04 at 06:00. In this case difference is 9 hours. Why???

It was because of daylight saving time.

Time difference between me and facebook(Los Angeles) sometimes was 8 sometimes 9 hours, because there was a moment when Denmakr alredy changed their time to summer time and los angeles - not.

The problem occured when event started "in winter time" and finished in summer time. In this case I needed to add one hour.

Comment: maybe difference is because of timezone,
may first command is getting time in your timezone & second one in GMT

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no. Differnce between my timezone and timezone of event creator is 1 hour. My timezone is GMT+2, events - GMT+1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is weird.

From [/fql/insights/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/)

> The end of the period during which the metrics were collected, expressed as a unix time **(which should always be midnight, Pacific Daylight Time)** or using the function end_time_date() which takes a date string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

2011-05-26T19:00:00 ===> 2011-05-26T19:00:00 **PDT** ===> Fri, 27 May 2011 02:00:00 GMT.